# JPA criteria query select from 3 tables based on id

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, hibernate-criteria

How can I achieve the query below as JPA criteria query :
sql

```
SELECT 
tab1.ID,
tab1.PROJECT_ID,
tab1.EMP_ID,
tab1.MONTH_ID,
tab1.MONTH,
tab2.projectName as ProjName,
tab3.empName as EmpName,
tab1.Table1
FROM 
Table1 tab1,Table2 tab2,Table3 tab3
WHERE 
Tab1.EMP_ID=tab3.ID AND tab1.PROJECT_ID=tab2.ID
I'm trying to make criteria query but I am unable to apply filters on 
that according to my requirement



CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteriaQuery = 

builder.createQuery(Object[].class);

Root<Table3> tab3 = criteriaQuery.from(Table3.class);

Root<Table1> tab1 = criteriaQuery.from(Table1.class);

Root<Table2> tab2 = criteriaQuery.from(Table2.class);

Path<Object> empPath = empRoot.get("id");

criteriaQuery.where(builder.equal(projectAllocationRoot.get("empId"),
  empRoot.get("id")));

criteriaQuery.multiselect(projectAllocationRoot);
        criteriaQuery.
```

---

```
Entity: JPA criteria query select from 3 tables based on id

 Table 1 
 long id ;
 @OneToMany
 Tanle2 projectId ; 
 @OneToMany   
 Table3 empId;
```

---

JPA criteria query select from 3 tables based on id
    Table 2
    long id ;
    long bpId ;
    String projectName;

---

JPA criteria query select from 3 tables based on id
    Table 3
    long id;
    String empName;
    String contactNum;

Comment: Can you share your entities? To understand their relationship type?

Comment: i want to Join table without a mapped association

Comment: Can you tell your final goal? I.e. why do you want it as a Criteria query?

Comment: @konstantinTriger its not necessary to use only Criteria query if you have any other alternative please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve any SQL with [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA), for example:

```java
FluentQuery query = FluentJPA.SQL((Table1 t1,
                                   Table2 t2,
                                   Table3 t3) -> {
    SELECT(t1.getId(), t1.getProjectId(), t1.getEmpId(),
           alias(t2.getProjectName(), MultiTab::getProjectName), t3.getEmpName());

    FROM(t1, t2, t3);
    WHERE(t1.getEmpId() == t3.getId() && t1.getProjectId() == t2.getId());
});

query.createQuery(em, MultiTab.class).getResultList();
```

produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT t0.id, t0.project_id, t0.emp_id, t1.projectName AS projName, t2.empName 
FROM tab1 t0, tab2 t1, tab3 t2 
WHERE ((t0.emp_id = t2.id) AND (t0.project_id = t1.id))
```

Declared projection class:

```java
@Tuple
@Data // lombok
public class MultiTab {
    long id;
    long projectId;
    long empId;
    @Column(name = "projName")
    String projectName;
    @Column(name = "empName")
    String empName;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but we cant use FluentJPA in our project. if you have any other alternative  please let me know thanks in advance..

Comment: @GauravJeswani i made relationship between entities